# Query retornando usuários que possuem um conjunto de registros de outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Desenvolvi um pequeno sistema em PHP e MySql que tem como objetivo armazenar e gerenciar usuários e seus respectivos cursos realizados.

Pesquisei alguns fóruns e páginas no Google, mas não encontrei nenhuma informação que me auxiliasse na resolução dessa query.

Estou com dificuldades para montar uma query que retorne todos os usuários que possuam um conjunto específico de cursos. Os cursos realizados ficam registrados em uma tabela separada.

Para facilitar a compreensão, segue abaixo um esquema resumido da tabela:

**Esquema resumido:**

```
  Tabela Usuarios
    usu_codigo - ID do usuário
    usu_nome   - Nome do Usuário

  Tabela Cursos
    cur_usuario - ID do usuário (chave estrangeira)
    cur_codigo  - ID do curso
```

**Exemplo:**

Bruno - possui os cursos 3,5,7,9,10,12
João  - possui os cursos 3,7,8,9,10,15
Maria - possui os cursos 2,5,7,10,11,13

Ao solicitar usuários que possuam os cursos 5,7,10, deverá retornar, portanto, Bruno e Maria. João não deve constar, pois ele não possui o curso 5.

Ou seja, o objetivo não se trata em retornar os usuários que possuam ao menos um dos cursos solicitados, e sim todos eles ao mesmo tempo.

Montei a estrutura resumida do Mysql no SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29a204/8

Agradeço quem puder me instruir com isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) esperada é a seguinte faça uma agrupamento na tabela de `cursos` e conforme a quantidade de parâmetros que no caso são 3 (`5, 7 e 10`) verifique quais desse retorna é igual a 3 e una o resultado com a tabela de `usuarios` com `JOIN`:

```
SELECT usuarios.* FROM usuarios 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT cur_usuario, 
  COUNT(cur_usuario) AS Q FROM cursos
  WHERE cur_codigo IN (5,7,10)
  GROUP BY cur_usuario
  HAVING COUNT(cur_usuario) = 3)
AS S ON S.cur_usuario = usuarios.usu_codigo
```

Resultado [ONLINE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29a204/45).

Comment: Olá, Novic! Muito obrigado pelo auxílio. Me ajudou bastante =D.  Então é necessário fazer o uso de um segundo select para obter o resultado esperado, não é mesmo? Um abraço!

Comment: @Luis sim é necessário utilizar uma preparação de resultados para depois buscar na outra tabela, se for util pra você vote como solução do seu problema.

Comment: Tenho uma nova dúvida. Caso não seja necessário q os usuários possuam tds os cursos citados e sim ao menos 1. Montei então a query para isso, que funciona perfeitamente.


select * from usuarios USU INNER JOIN cursos CUR ON USU.usu_codigo=CUR.cur_usuario 
where CUR.cur_codigo in (5,7,10) group by USU.usu_codigo order by USU.usu_nome asc


Se o usuário possui o curso 5, será que a query ainda assim percorrerá para saber se ele possui também os cursos 7 e 10? Se realmente houver essas verificações desnecessárias, existe uma maneira de otimizar isso?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29a204/51

Comment: Sim ele percorrer linha a linha em busca da comparação proposta, mas, eu usaria assim: `select distinct USU.* from usuarios USU INNER JOIN cursos CUR ON USU.usu_codigo=CUR.cur_usuario where CUR.cur_codigo in (5,7,10) order by USU.usu_nome asc` @Luis (**se tiver duvidas a mais pode abrir outro pergunta**)

Comment: O `DISTINCT` faz com que algum registro não se repita e no caso o `GROUP BY` e desnecessário porque você não precisa contar ou sumarizar nada ... @Luis

Comment: vamos excluir esse monte de comentários @Luis?